# "No such module" using Xcode 8, even after installing the Pod

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have gone through all the answers for the above error, but none of them really helped me.

I do not encounter an error while importing some of the pods (Firebase, Twilio Video Etc.), however while importing others (Alamofire, Stripe, Sentry etc) results in an Error (No such module). I have also tried re-installing all the pods, but it still doesn't work.

I have spend more than half a day trying to resolve this issue without success. Could someone please help me in resolving this ?

[image: No such module Error]

Below are the framework search paths from my project Build Settings.
[image]

The error still persists even after adding the pod/framework (Alamofire) in linked frameworks and libraries.
[image: Linked frameworks and libraries]

Comment: did you build the project after installing the pod? you need to build once after installing pods so that your code knows that modules have been added.

Comment: I am unable to build the project, as it comes with a complier error, 'No such module'

Comment: @kurrodu Try to quit Xcode completely, then uninstall and install Pods! And after cleaning derived data check ASAP.

Comment: Try to re install alamofire pod.